# Bluetooth Stack unresponsive after a while for detecting BLE devices

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, altbeacon

I am trying to detect beacons using altbeacon. I had to configure a foreground service using worker and few other options to make it work in all devices including chinese OEMs.

The problem I face currently is that after running service for a strech of a week continuously, the bluetooth stack freezes. I used the bluetoohtMedic class to reset the stack with a bit on configuration, but that toggles the bluetooth on and off continuously for about 2-5 minutes.

Is there a way to avoid this?

[image: Bluetooth toggle]

Comment: Maybe complain to your phone manufacturer that their Bluetooth stack is buggy? Does logcat show any error that could be the reason?

Comment: This happens once a while with every manufacturer, let me get the logs